# function service returning undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Im storing in a variable a boolean value to check if a user is admin or not, in my function that i call the service i can receive the result value (true or false), but than in the variable vm.isAdmin im getting a undefined.

```
vm.isAdmin = accountType("admin");
function accountType(type){
    UserService.isAccount(type).then(
        function (result) {
           console.log("result");
           console.log(result);
           return result;
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UserService.isAccount returns promise and you use it by setting anonymous function in then method but your main function is not the same, anonymous function used in accountType function is called asynchronous so result will be much after your function accountType will end. Your accountType function should return promise as well or use callback functions.

try to to this this way ( callback functions ):

```
       function accountType(type,funcYes,funcNo){

            UserService.isAccount(type).then(
                function (result) {

                  if (result===type)//change this if
                  funcYes();
                  else
                      funcNo();

                }
            );
        }
```

example usage:

```
   accountType("admin",function(){ 
   //code for yes  
   },function(){  
   // code for no
   });
```

Comment: I already made it, but still giving me a "c {$$state: Object}"

Comment: You will never get boolean, boolean can be assigned in function which will be called after promise. Promise is asynchronous, you must uderstand that asynchronous function not calls in line where they are in code, it runs some while after that in the same scope. Check my code and try it.

Answer (score 1):

`UserService.isAccount` seems to return a promise, so you have to use it this way:

```
UserService.isAccount('admin')
.then(function (result) {
        vm.isAdmin = result;
    });
```

So, that the result is assigned when it's available.